# Extract hardcoded values from binary

Tags: c++, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am working with 5 other individuals to predict air pollution. I have generated values that I am hesitant to share with these 5 others (group project, marked individually). Say I have some values that I wouldn't like exposed, I compile the source code and run the binary, this binary takes in environmental data then sends the output to a central party (in this case, my professor), is there anything that could be in the source code that reveals the values to anyone when sending this info to the professor? I.e. can my professor see these values or my group?

The bulk of the source code isn't written by me, but I worked on the value generation.

Comment: What exactly does a potential attacker have access to?

Comment: I think the group I am working with is very friendly with another group. this wont help with grades if someone in the group shared it with the other group

Comment: If you do not trust your group and they have access to both the values and the source code, there is no way of preventing them from sharing it.

Comment: They dont have access to values, but they have access to source code. the values i generate and i compile the binary and this then send data to the professor. I was wondering if they could extract using some method as the data is being sent to professor on cloud